# JSON-schema. How-to Require a key with a specific value, Else require a different key with any value

Tags: json, jsonschema

### So the requirements of the schema are,

1. Must have "must_1",
2. Must have one of either;

- "key_2" with a value of true (boolean)
- "key_3"

3. When "key_2" has a value of false or doesn't exist, "key_3" must exist
4. May have "optional_4" (This is actually quite a few extra keys, all of which will be described)
5. May not have any undescribed keys

So these should pass

```json
"pass_1": {
    "must_1": 1,
    "key_2": false,
    "key_3": "ewe"
},
"pass_2": {
    "must_1": 2,
    "key_3": "ewe"
},
"pass_3": {
    "must_1": 3,
    "key_2": true
},
```

And this should fail

```json
"fail_1": {
    "must_1": 7,
    "key_2": false
},
```

### My attempt so far

However this passes "fail_1"

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": ["must_1"],
    "dependentRequired": {
        "not": {
            "key_2": ["key_3"]
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        ...
    }
}
```

This one's really stumped me.

#### Copy and paste code (schema and tests)

I've been using [jsonschemalint](https://jsonschemalint.com/#!/version/draft-04/markup/json) as my comparison tool

```json
// My current none-working schema
{
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        "[^\\s]+": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": ["must_1"],
            "dependentRequired": {
                "not": {
                    "key_2": ["key_3"]
                }
            },
            "properties": {
                "must_1": {
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "key_2": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "key_3": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "optional_4": {}

            }
        }
    }
}

// Tests, tests with "pass_#" should pass, tests with "fail_#" should fail :)
// 1-6 pass tests, 1-7 fail tests

{
    "pass_1": {
        "must_1": 1,
        "key_2": false,
        "key_3": "ewe"
    },
    "pass_2": {
        "must_1": 2,
        "key_3": "ewe"
    },
    "pass_3": {
        "must_1": 3,
        "key_2": true
    },
    "pass_4": {
        "must_1": 4,
        "key_2": false,
        "key_3": "ewe",
        "optional_4": "optional"
    },
    "pass_5": {
        "must_1": 5,
        "key_3": "ewe",
        "optional_4": "optional"
    },
    "pass_6": {
        "must_1": 6,
        "key_2": true,
        "optional_4": "optional"
    },
    "fail_1": {
        "must_1": 7,
        "key_2": false
    },
    "fail_2": {
        "must_1": 1,
        "key_2": false,
        "key_3": "ewe",
        "undescribed_5": "undescribed"
    },
    "fail_3": {
        "must_1": 2,
        "key_3": "ewe",
        "undescribed_5": "undescribed"
    },
    "fail_4": {
        "must_1": 3,
        "key_2": true,
        "undescribed_5": "undescribed"
    },
    "fail_5": {
        "must_1": 4,
        "key_2": false,
        "key_3": "ewe",
        "optional_4": "optional",
        "undescribed_5": "undescribed"
    },
    "fail_6": {
        "must_1": 5,
        "key_3": "ewe",
        "optional_4": "optional",
        "undescribed_5": "undescribed"
    },
    "fail_7": {
        "must_1": 6,
        "key_2": true,
        "optional_4": "optional",
        "undescribed_5": "undescribed"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came to, passes all tests. Probably not the best implementation

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": ["must_1"],
    "if": {
        "properties": {
            "key_2": {
                "const": false
            }
        }
    },
    "then": {
        "required": ["key_3"]
    },
    "properties": {
        ...
    }
```